# Keyboards with the number pad in the middle?

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

I'm suffering from early RSI symptoms and am looking for a way to avoid injury.  My physiotherapist has determined that the worst thing I seem to be doing is using my mouse at such a weird angle.  The problem for me is, I keep my keyboard positioned such that my left and right forearms are angled in the same amount, i.e., my body is centred roughly with the B key.  On my current keyboard, which is not a split, this means the wide Enter key, the arrow keys, and the number pad all jut out to the right before I have space for my mouse.  I have a medium-width frame, but even still, this leaves my wrist at a really awkward angle when using the mouse.  I'd prefer not to have to push my keyboard out of the way every time I switch between the two, but I do use the num pad occasionally, so I wouldn't want a keyboard without that.

I think it'd be ideal to have about a 30-50 cm space between the left and right halves of the keyboard, so my arms are more perpendicular to my collarbone, and the arrow keys and number pad in the middle, maybe even with the numbers on a 45 degree angle, so I could configure them for use with either hand.

(In case you were wondering, then a touch-screen with a stylus that has a right-click modifier button for mousing, because otherwise the mouse pad would be right where I'd put the right half of the home row, in the most natural position for my right arm while sitting.)

With that much space, you could fit so many custom keys for things that you normally use two-key combos for...or you could detach them completely (save for a wire) and just have, you know, actual desktop showing through.

What's the closest keyboard you've seen to this?

Comment: Closest is the Comfort Keyboard Original: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CC3KBQG/ref=as_li_qf_sp_asin_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=B00CC3KBQG&linkCode=as2&tag=lorensrme-20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.thehumansolution.com/keyboards.html

I've been looking here at some keyboards (I've got severe Carpal Tunnel).  The Kinesis keyboards are nice, but there where a few there with the number pad in the middle.

[alt text http://us.st12.yimg.com/us.st.yimg.com/I/thehumansolution_2020_3491616](http://us.st12.yimg.com/us.st.yimg.com/I/thehumansolution_2020_3491616)

[alt text http://us.st12.yimg.com/us.st.yimg.com/I/thehumansolution_2016_1198996](http://us.st12.yimg.com/us.st.yimg.com/I/thehumansolution_2016_1198996)

Answer (score 4):

I use a keyboard with the numeric keypad on the left hand side. This allows me to bring my mouse in closer on the right hand side, allowing for a more natural position. I am right handed. You can see the keyboard I use [here](http://www.keyboardco.com/shortboard/buy_the_lefty.asp).

[image]
<sub>(source: [keyboardco.com](http://www.keyboardco.com/shortboard/keyboard_images/beige_left_handed_ps2_usb_high_quality_keyboard_thumb.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

In line with Joel Coehoorn's suggestion, I find that a trackpoint (aka "nipple") is even more ergonomical than a touchpad. Lenovo's [USB Keyboard with UltraNav](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-45868) has both.

My mouse usage is minimal, though, because I focus on using the keyboard for everything. This might not be easy in your particular development environment.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/45940_usb_key.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Just an advice. I was also suffering from the RSI symptoms, up to the shoulders. I've tried MS and Logitech ergonomic keyboard without succes. It was even worth than before because the mouse was more distant than before.

Then I founded the [TypeMatrix Keyboard](http://www.typematrix.com/ezr2030/dvorak.html) and it reduce my RSI to nearly nothing.

Unfortunately, they are hard to found for non US nor Canada citizens.

[image]
<sub>(source: [typematrix.com](http://www.typematrix.com/ezr2030/images/qwerty_new.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I did try a [PCD Maltron](https://web.archive.org/web/20100830125810/http://www.maltron.com:80/maltron-about.html) keyboard for a while when I was having some problems with referred pain, but I never really got used to it.  I'm left handed, so my mouse is quite close to the keyboard.  If you're having trouble with your mouse being too far out to the right you could try a small footprint keyboard such as a [Happy Hacking Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Hacking_Keyboard) and a [Separate Numeric Pad](https://web.archive.org/web/20071215011110/http://www.nextag.com:80/numeric-pad/search-html) on the left or somewhere else to get a more clement key layout.

I also learned to use a mouse with both hands - you might also try learning to use a mouse left-handed.

[alt text http://www.maltron.com/images/keyboards/maltron-usb-dual-l90-uk-mac-qwerty-gray-1-600.jpg](http://www.maltron.com/images/keyboards/maltron-usb-dual-l90-uk-mac-qwerty-gray-1-600.jpg)
[image]
<sub>(source: [geekstuff4u.com](http://www.geekstuff4u.com/images/HHKLB.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Small alphabet footprint is actually the problem with my current one--the angle it forces my wrists into is almost as bad as the far-out-mouse makes it.  But left-handed mousing might be a good call, I'll definitely try it.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I had wrist problems, too.

What worked for me was changing my posture, how I hold myself, my arms. I move my keyboard and mouse around, I change my position and the position of those two.
Additionally I use keyboard shortcuts a lot to not overuse the mouse.

This way I got rid of my wrist problems without replacing keyboard or mouse.

Answer (score 2):

As a fellow RSI suffer, I hope one of these helps out.

The ErgoMagic and ErgoFlex keyboards are split into 3 sections, and you can position the number pad in the middle.

The ErgoFlex is a flat design:

http://www.safecomputingtips.com/blog/ergonomic-keyboard/ergoflex-keyboard/
http://www.comfortkeyboard.com/keyboards_ergoflex.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [safecomputingtips.com](http://www.safecomputingtips.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/ergoflex-keyboard.jpg))</sub>

The ErgoMagic has adjustable tilts for each section:

http://www.comfortkeyboard.com/keyboards_ergomagic.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [comfortkeyboard.com](http://www.comfortkeyboard.com/images/keyboard_ergomagic.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The main problem about keyboards is not the keyboard layout or form factor, the main problem of keyboards is the layout. I had really strong RSI problems, to the point I could barely type (only by when accepting major pain!) for two weeks. I couldn't touch a keyboard for 3 weeks till it finally got better. After that the problems always came back every now and then. I tried different keyboards as well. I have a GoldTouch split keyboard, a Microsoft Natural split one, I have even the TypeMatrix one that gizmo mentioned, but it all helped little.

Then I discovered the [Dvorak layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard). At first I thought it's a silly idea, but I took that route. It was a hard training and it took me quite a long time, but now it's the only one I keep using, as it's the only one I can type on for ours without any RSI symptoms. At first things seem to have gotten worse, but that's only because a new layout will lead to new finger movements.

Recently I found out about [Colemak](http://colemak.com/), another alternative to QWERTY, it seems even more promising than Dvorak; I'm just trying to learn it... and I have a hard time again.

Another thing that helped me much more than replacing the keyboard is replacing the mouse. I'm not using a mouse any longer, I'm using a trackball.

[image]
<sub>(source: [arstechnica.com](http://members.arstechnica.com/x/archangelha/logitech-trackball.jpg))</sub>

And after I tried plenty of keyboard (I have more than 20 at home, no kidding!) I stayed with the Microsoft Natural 4000 keyboard. It might be huge, but I can type very well on it.

Comment: Have you tried Colemak?  Strange concept to me.

Comment: @JasonShort See answer. Meanwhile I use Colemak elusively. You can type a lot more on just the home row than with Dvorak. It may not be faster than Dvorak which has been optimized for speed (almost all the fastest typist of the world use Dvorak) but it is more pleasant to type as that's what Colemak has been optimized for. The goals of Colemak were: Stay as close as possible to QWERTY for quick learning but optimize that layout for pleasant typing (use home row a lot, small travel paths for fingers, use rolling movements where possible)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any keyboards like that, but what might help is a keyboard with a built-in touchpad (like for a laptop) that you can use instead of your other mouse for *some* of your mousing:  small adjustments, quick taps to click, etc, to avoid having to go out to the mouse.

Comment: You can get a keyboard with a built-in touchpad, like the Logitech DiNovo Edge